# Clearing a text input field after clearing another one

Tags: javascript, textbox

I have 2 text `<input>`s. I want textbox1 be cleared after textbox2 is cleared by either deleting textbox2's text or clicking the "X" button on the left side of the textbox. Is there a way to detect a clearing of a textbox or add an event to the "X" button?

Answer (score 4):

you can use keyup event on textbox1 for know when textbox is empty

```js
$('#txt1').on('keyup', function() {
  if ($('#txt1').val().trim().length == 0) {
    $('#txt2').val('');
  }
});
$('.deleteText').click(function() {
  $('#txt1').val('');
  $('#txt2').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt1" value='delete it' /><span class='deleteText'>X</span>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="txt2" value='test value' />
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="txtbox1">
<input type="text" id="txtbox2">
<button id="btnX">X</button>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("txtbox2").addEventListener("keyup", handler);
document.getElementById("btnX").addEventListener("click", handler);

function handler() {
    txt1 = document.getElementById("txtbox1")
    txt2 = document.getElementById("txtbox2")
    if(txt2.value == ""){
        txt1.value = ""
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p33k55pw/)